# Rabbit saving extra bytes for AMQP 1.0 messages

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have an environment where some AMQP 1.0 and some AMQP 0.9.1 clients need to write to/read from a RabbitMQ queue. I enabled the AMQP 1.0 rabbit plugin and it is working, but I get extra bytes in body for each AMQP 1.0 message.

I'm sending messages through AMQP1.0 by using `rhea` (typescript):

```js
const connection: Connection = new Connection (
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5672,
    id: 'my_id',
    reconnect: true
  }
);

const senderName = "sender01";
const senderOptions: SenderOptions = {
  name: senderName,
  target: {
    address: "target.queue"
  },
  onError: (context: EventContext) => {},
  onSessionError: (context: EventContext) => {}
};

await connection.open();
const sender: Sender = await connection.createSender(senderOptions);
sender.send({
  body: JSON.stringify({"one": "two", "three": "four"}),
  content_encoding: 'UTF-8',
  content_type: 'application/json'
});
console.log("sent");
await sender.close();

await connection.close();
console.log("connection closed");
```

This example works but this is what is stored in the queue:

[image]

The base64 encoded message is `AFN3oRx7Im9uZSI6InR3byIsInRocmVlIjoiZm91ciJ9`, which after decoding becomes:

```
Sw{"one":"two","three":"four"}
```

There is an additional `Sw` which I didn't send.

I tried setting up a java client with the official RabbitMQ library (which talks AMQP 0.9.1) to see if those extra bytes were sent to clients:

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.basicConsume(
  "target.queue",
  true,
  (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  },
  ignored -> {}
);
```

This is the output:

```
 [x] Received ' Sw�{"one":"two","three":"four"}'
```

The weird thing is that if I try consuming the exact same message with an AMQP 1.0 client, those extra bytes don't appear in the received message body, extra bytes appear only when publishing with AMQP 1.0 and subscribing with AMQP 0.9.1.

Why is that? Is there any way to avoid extra bytes when using both AMQP versions?

---

**UPDATE**

I also tried with SwiftMQ:

```java
int nMsgs = 100;

int qos = QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE;
AMQPContext ctx = new AMQPContext(AMQPContext.CLIENT);
String host = "localhost";
int port = 5672;
String queue = "target.queue";

try {

  Connection connection = new Connection(ctx, host, port, false);
  connection.setContainerId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  connection.setIdleTimeout(-1);
  connection.setMaxFrameSize(1024 * 4);
  connection.setExceptionListener(Exception::printStackTrace);
  connection.connect();
  {

    Session session = connection.createSession(10, 10);
    Producer p = session.createProducer(queue, qos);
    for (int i = 0; i < nMsgs; i++) {
      AMQPMessage msg = new AMQPMessage();
      System.out.println("Sending " + i);
      msg.setAmqpValue(new AmqpValue(new AMQPString("{\"one\":\"two\",\"three\":\"four\"}")));
      p.send(msg);
    }
    p.close();
    session.close();
  }
  connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The issue is still there, but the first bytes changed, now I get:

```
[x] Received '□�□□□□□□□w�{"one":"two","three":"four"}'
```

Comment: Using 0.9.1 on both sides with the same logic elsewhere works? Why not just stick with that on both sides? There are substantial differences between the two specs.

Comment: @theMayer Using 0.9.1 on both sides works, but I have some components in the ecosystem (like Azure Event Hub) that can only communicate using AMQP 1.0, so I need to support both protocols.

Comment: Probably is due to specification differences between the two protocols. I would recommend doing a transform in your app as a workaround for 0-9-1 clients. I agree it is odd and a good question.

Comment: @theMayer I think it's a matter of differences between protocols too, but I thought the AMQP 1.0 plugin was going to handle those for me. Let's see if someone has a clue, maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I did look into it a bit, but didn't find anything clear, only indications that there were some differences in encoding. Keep in mind it could also be the particular client you're using, as the client would also need to respect the protocol differences.

Comment: @theMayer As said I'm expecting the plugin to handle the differences for me. If I use RabbitMQ I'm expecting all protocol plugins to produce the exact same output, it wouldn't make sense to have a plugin which claims to deal with another protocol and then requires you handle it manually. Also, another difference is that AMQP 1.0 messages come base64 encoded by default, while AMQP 0.9.1 ones don't. That's also weird.

Comment: The plug-in is on the server side, and it has AMQP 1.0 as the defined interface. If you supply AMQP 0-9-1 as the input, it would not be reasonable to expect it to work. I don't know how compatible the two are, but I would not expect a message formatted as AMQP 1.0 to be compatible with one formatted as 0-9-1.

Comment: @theMayer I do expect it to work correctly, because it's what they say on [the official github page](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0): *It will listen on the standard AMQP port, 5672. To reconfigure this, do so as you would for 0-9-1.* ***Clients connecting with 0-9-1 will continue to work on the same port.*** I can try changing port for AMQP 1.0 (I will try today) but I don't think this will solve the issue

Comment: I don’t think you’re hearing what I am saying. If AMQP 1.0 has a different encoding format for message bodies, which I think it does, then this is something a 0-9-1 client is going to be unable to deal with.

Comment: Can you try doing the binary encoding yourself and sending a byte array as a payload?

Comment: @theMayer I'm hearing what you say. I know for sure that AMQP 1.0 has a different encoding format than 0.9.1, what I'm saying is that the plugin should be able to handle it. If the payload of my message is "hello", then "hello" should be stored in the queue: if the format is 0.9.1 I expect Rabbit to decode it accordingly; if the format is 1.0 I expect the plugin to detect that and decode the message accordingly, without leaving weird bytes in the queue. I also tried with a byte array and the result unfortunately is the same.

Comment: Have you tried longer bytes? Is the beginning sequence the same such that you could strip it? I suspect what you're seeing is the length parameter that gets prepended, but I don't know.

Comment: @theMayer It does change, for  `{"one":"two","three":"four","five":"six"}` I get  `Sw�){"one":"two","three":"four","five":"six"}`, it also seems to be changing with the specific client: I tried with SwiftMQ, the same message becomes `□�□□□□□□□w�{"one":"two","three":"four","five":"six"}`... I have really no clue what's going on here.

Comment: @BackSlash - thank you for the code to reproduce this. Could you please let me know what version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you're using?

Comment: @LukeBakken I'm using the docker tagged `rabbitmq:3.7.11-management`, which has RabbitMQ 3.7.11 with Erlang 21.2.5. I `bash`ed into the container and enabled the plugin with `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_amqp1_0`

Comment: Thanks. The `rhea` client library is adding the extra data as part of the message body encoding, and we're discussing whether or not the `rabbitmq_amqp1_0` plugin should handle that or not. If an issue is created on GitHub, I'll post it back here.

Comment: @LukeBakken I edited the question and posted the code for SwiftMQ. The GitHub page states it has been tested but I can reproduce the same issue. Please see if it helps. Thank you!

Comment: Right, these libraries are adding the data - it's not just `rhea`. The question is if RabbitMQ should do anything with it. If that data is stripped, and then an AMQP 1.0 client consumes the message, what happens then???

Comment: @LukeBakken That's a good question. That's something that would happen in a scenario where the publisher is an AMQP 0-9-1 client and the subscriber is an AMQP 1.0 client: 0-9-1 doesn't add that data, 1.0 might expect to receive it. Let me put up an example and see what happens.

Comment: @BackSlash if you could move your initial question and follow-ups to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) that would be great. Please share your code as gists or as attachments and not in-line. This way more people can participate. I will keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @LukeBakken - I tried posting a few times but my post gets deleted as soon as I publish it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/zO6ZUy8zw-U

Comment: @BackSlash I'm assuming that you see your post went through. New users are moderated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/QBsc_wCuTBs/8hbAW0SWBQAJ) which clarifies how to encode the payload and avoid these extra bytes:

> if AMQP 1.0 client sends message to 0-9-1 client and encodes her payload as binary in a "data section" (i.e. not in amqp-sequence section, not in amqp-value section) the 0-9-1 client shall get the the complete payload without any extra bytes